# Vertical stripes with Radeon 3200U

Tags: 20.04, opengl, amdgpu, mesa, opencl

I'm getting a weird problem with a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 install.
Everything works fine, except native Linux games. On Rimworld, I get a striped picture, in Stardew Valley (Steam), at best all text boxes display asian languages.
I've tried many things, oibaf drivers, weird grub options, etc... but to no avail.
[Rimworld screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAsde.jpg)

The weirdest thing is that all my Windows games with WINE work perfectly.
Have you ever come across something like this ?

TIA

Additionnally, I tried reinstalling everything openGL-related, but still...
[Unigine Valley screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn16Q.jpg)

I also tried changing the memory... Same difference.
I reinstalled Windows 10, no problem whatsoever, so that rules out a hardware fault.
This is infuriating.

Comment: What graphics drivers are you using?

Comment: I'm using amdgpu drivers, from the oibaf ppa. But I had the same problems from the official repositories, so I'm really puzzled there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put "(SOLVED)" in your question title in the question answer site. Write your own answer as the solution to the problem by clicking "Write an Answer" button. Then after the required wait time accept your answer as the correct one by placing the green check mark ✅ next to your answer. That will indicate the question has been answered to your satisfaction and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, it's a Mesa bug.
http://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/2814
Starting the problematic apps with AMD_DEBUG=nodmacopyimage solves the problem.
And it also doubles my fps in everything else...